# Failed to create kernel channel: installing Ubuntu (ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso) onto System76 laptop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, usb, ubuntu-16.04

I created a bootable USB for

I burned to USB with https://etcher.io/ on my Mac OSX machine (just like Disk Utility) as stated in [this guide](http://support.system76.com/articles/install-ubuntu/).

Then I inserted into laptop, held F7, got to boot screen, selected Install Ubuntu, and choose to completely wipe the disks and reinstall clean.

I followed all the standard steps, but after the installer told me it was finished and needed to restart, restarting simply lead to a dead screen, with four lines of cryptic error messages:

```
[   5.xxxxxx] nouveau xxx:xx:xx.x priv HUBO xxxxx xxxxx (xxxxxx)
[   5.xxxxxx] nouveau xxx:xx:xx.x DRM: failed to create kernel channel. -22
[   6.xxxxxx] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] No caching mode page found
[   6.xxxxxx] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
```

And that's it. I've tried redoing it, keeping the USB in during the reboot, keeping it out, trying the "Try Ubuntu" and then installing. None of them work, though some just get me to a black screen without these messages.

Anyone know what's going on and how I fix it?

Comment: What going one is you have a Nvidia Graphics and, considering the reported problem, you need the additional boot parameter `nomodeset` until you install the recommended Nvidia drivers.

Comment: OK, well that's good to hear. How do I enable `nomodeset `? The guide I posted said to press F6, but that key does nothing for meet on the boot screen.

Comment: Just do CTRL+ALT+DEL and it will reboot to the Grub menu where you can edit the default entry to add the parameter in the same line that usually starts with "quiet splash".

Comment: Would this be before I install? I can only get to the edit menu when my USB is inserted and I interrupt boot that way. Without a usb drive in, all my boots are completely black screens..

Comment: I can only get to the Aptio Setup Utility which doesn't appear to have any way to see or edit entries.

Comment: I was able to successfully get to the edit screen. Adding `nomodeset` didn't work. Still getting a black screen on boot up and no Ubuntu to be seen.